# What is the Core in “Project Almanac”?

Tags: project-almanac

I just watched *Project Almanac* and I’m curious as to what the Core is. I know that it enables an object or person to time travel, but what exactly is it?

Comment: I think you've described it about as well as it's described in the film + supporting materials. It's made of [handwavium](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AppliedPhlebotinum?from=Main.Handwavium)

Answer (score 2):

I think that it might be a small particle accelerator powerful enough to create a wormhole connecting the present to a point in the past, which closes when the core goes back to the present or is destroyed. There are three major facts in the movie to support this theory:

> 1. The core uses hydrogen as a power source
> 2. It looks like a mini version of the LHC
> 3. Whenever it is powered up, it generates a powerful magnetic field around it

This also explains why the camera flickers whenever the core is activated: the electromagnetic field surrounding the core interferes with the camera.

1 is stated in the movie. 3 is shown by the car being pulled towards the spot that the travelers activated the machine the first time, but before they went back in time. For 2, these links will show the Core as having a similar shape to the LHC (for the second link, it's the second picture after the poster):

www.xente.mundo-r.com/rcid/images/image/LHC_map.jpg

horrornews.net/94383/film-review-project-almanac-2015

Comment: Do you have any sources to back this up?  Is the part in 
the blockquote an actual quote?  Answers should have some evidence; please read [answer].

Comment: The first one is stated in the movie. The third one is shown by the car being pulled towards the spot that the travelers activated the machine the first time, but before they went back in time. For the second one, these links will show the Core as having a similar shape to the LHC (for the second link, it's the second picture after the poster): www.xente.mundo-r.com/rcid/images/image/LHC_map.jpg https://horrornews.net/94383/film-review-project-almanac-2015/

Comment: The point of asking was to prod you to add that to the answer.  :)